# Angular 2 npm install showing error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

whenever i am trying to install npm. It showing some error.Please help me thanks in advance.

```
[Error][1]
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Add your package.json dependencies

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message, you'll see you're requesting an invalid version of the `@progress/kendo-angular-grid` package. Have a look at the registry page for that package at npmjs.org, and change the version number to something valid in your package.json.